# When to use Materialized Views?

Tags: cassandra

I'm learning Cassandra now and I understand I should make a table for each query. I'm not sure when I should make separate tables or materialized views. For example, I have the following queries for users and posts:

`users_by_id
users_by_email
users_by_session_key`

`posts_by_id
posts_by_category
posts_by_user`

Should I always use materialized views?

It seems to me that if you want to keep the Posts or Users consistent across queries, then I have to use materialized views. However materialized views I read have a `read before write` latency.

On the other hand, if I use different tables, am I supposed to make 3 Inserts every time a new post is created? I noticed that I get the error `batch with conditions cannot span multiple tables`, which means I have to insert it one at a time into each separate table, which can cause consistency problems if one of the queries fails. (A batch statement, would fail all 3 if one of them failed).

So, since it makes sense to have consistency, then it seems to me that I will always want to use materialized views, and have to take the `read before write` penalty.

I guess my other question is when would it ever be okay for data to be inconsistent?

So hoping someone can provide more clarity for me for how to handle multiple queries in cassandra on a 'theoretical model` like Users or Posts. Should I be using materialized views? If I use 3 different tables for each model, how do I keep them consistent? Just hope that all 3 inserts don't fail? Doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3):

Read my deep dive blog post for all the trade-offs when using materialized views. Once you understand the trade-offs, choose wisely: http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=1930

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't always use materialized views. The perfect solution is a interface for your database. In this application, you handle all your different tables. But there's are also some use case for the materialized views: If you haven't the time for this application but you need this feature, use materialized views. You have a performance trade off but in this scenario, the time is more important. If you also need real updates instead of upserts on all tables: use materialized views.

Batch is useful for buffering or putting data-sets with the same partition key together. For example: You have a high data troughput application. Between your heartbeats or between execution another query with QUORUM, you got 10 other events with the same partition key. But you won't execute them because you're waiting for a successful response. If a success comes back, you execute a batch query. But please keep in mind: Use only a batch for the same partition keys.

Generally, remember one important thing: Cassandra has an eventually consistency model. That means: If you use qourum, you will have consistency but not every time. If your application needs a full consistency, not only eventually use another solution. E.g. SQL with sharding. Cassandra is optimized for writes and you will only get happy when you're using the cassandra features.

Some performance tips:
If you need a better consistency: Use QUORUM, never use ALL. And, generally, write you queries standalone. Sometimes batch is useful. Don't execute queries with ALLOW FILTERING. Don't use token ranges or IN operator on partition keys :)

Comment: In your first paragraph you mention you mention the tradeoff is time vs performance. I have time so id like to make these 3 different tables instead of materialized views. However Im still confused what is the proper way to keep the data in the 3 Posts table consistent. (Btw i dont mean consistency across replicas when i say consistency, but consistency in data for the 3 Posts tables). My worry is that my server makes 3 inserts to create a post but at one point my server fails. Now i have 'posts_by_id' but no 'posts_By_category' table. So how would i handle data consistency of 3 tables?

Comment: You can do two things: Use QUOURUM or create a batch repair process. The first one is easy to implement: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

For the second, you need a Message Queue System like kafka. You create a fast stream processing application. The second application, in your batch stream, does only one thing: Repair broken tables. The second solution is really fast, nice for realtime analytics, but the first one is more secure. I think, in your case, the first one is the better choice.